# Execute command only on first timer tick event in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, timer

I am running some code at every tick interval of a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object tick.

There are some pieces of code that I would only like to execute once at the first tick. I would like to avoid using an if statement with some global counter simply because I don't want to have to evaluate the statement at every tick afterwards (performance wise it seems rather expensive considering I would like to run the tick events hundreds of thousands of times as fast as possible).

So my question is does anyone know of any tricks to do this? Also, I guess in a more general programming context, I'm interested to learn about what possible solutions/patterns there are to execute pieces of code within loops only once without using if statements.

EDIT: Thinking about this, is it possible to have have 2 pointers for 2 separate routines, where one includes the code to be executed the first time and the other doesn't. At the end of the first routine, the pointer to the routine can be switched to the other routine?

Comment: Nothing that a simple Boolean variable could not do.  It is not expensive, it takes less than a nanosecond.  You can do it more than a *trillion* times per second.  A timer can't tick faster than 64 times per second.  It is rather odd to want to do this "first time" with a delay instead of just doing it immediately when you enable the timer btw.

Comment: Thanks, @HansPassant. That seems to be the general consensus. What do you mean by a delay? I do want to do it immediately when I enable the timer but would like to confine the code to tick handler sub for 'tidiness' I suppose.

Comment: Wrong kind of "tidiness" of course.  Still nothing you could not solve with a lamda.

Answer (score 1):

Just write another sub to start the timer. In this sub first execute the code you want to execute only once and then start the timer.

```
Private Sub StartTimer(ByRef tmr as Timer)
  DoStuffOnce()
  tmr.Start()
End Sub
```

If this is not what you want then you need to elaborate your question.

By the way, checking a boolean variable takes around a few microseconds, I doubt that this would be the rate determining step in your code.